# How to get change history for a specific file in git repository

Tags: git, diff, history

I would like to do something like:

```
git history my_file
```

### possible output

```
2010-05-16
+ add this line
+ more code here

2010-05-15
+ delete code below
- bad code
- more bad codd

2010-05-12
+ changes made here
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
git log -p -- filename
```

Answer (score 8):

The closest to what you want would be, from [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log -p -U0 --pretty=format:%ai -- filename
```

- `-p`: as [Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851918/how-to-get-change-history-for-a-specific-file-in-git-repository/2851931#2851931): Generate patch
- `-U0`: Generate diffs with 0 lines of context instead of the usual three.
- `--pretty=format:%ai`: precede the patch output with the author date, ISO 8601 format.

Example:

```
/c/Prog/Git/git2/git (master)
$ git log -p -U0 --pretty=format:%ai -- wt-status.c
2010-03-24 16:25:43 -0700
2010-03-13 23:00:27 +0100
diff --git a/wt-status.c b/wt-status.c
index e0e915e..5848f1c 100644
--- a/wt-status.c
+++ b/wt-status.c
@@ -306,0 +307,2 @@ static void wt_status_collect_changes_worktree(struct wt_status *s)
+       if (!s->show_untracked_files)
+               DIFF_OPT_SET(&rev.diffopt, IGNORE_UNTRACKED_IN_SUBMODULES);

2010-03-08 22:58:09 -0800
diff --git a/wt-status.c b/wt-status.c
index 5807fc3..dcaec7f 100644
--- a/wt-status.c
+++ b/wt-status.c
@@ -292,0 +293 @@ static void wt_status_collect_changes_index(struct wt_status *s)
+       struct setup_revision_opt opt;
@@ -295,2 +296,4 @@ static void wt_status_collect_changes_index(struct wt_status *s)
-       setup_revisions(0, NULL, &rev,
-               s->is_initial ? EMPTY_TREE_SHA1_HEX : s->reference);
+       memset(&opt, 0, sizeof(opt));
+       opt.def = s->is_initial ? EMPTY_TREE_SHA1_HEX : s->reference;
+       setup_revisions(0, NULL, &rev, &opt);
+
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra params :)

Answer (score 4):

A nice UI view of the file history is also given if you pass the file to gitk, which comes with your Git installation.

On Windows...

```
gitk.cmd <file>
```

Comment: It's just `gitk path/to/file` on osx. I also think it's the same on linux. I had to upgrade git to get the gitk command.